# Using one member to intialize another member

Tags: c++, initialization

```
class A{
    public:
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    A(int n):a(n),b(a){}
};
int main()
{
    A obj=5;
  cout<<obj.a<<obj.b;}
```

and

```
   class A{
    public:
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    A(int n):b(n),a(b){}
};
int main()
{
    A obj=5;
  cout<<obj.a<<obj.b;}
```

The output of the first code is 55, and the output of the second code is 05.

I can't understand. I think they are the same:
a(or b) is intialized with n, and then intializes the other member. The output should both be 55.

Please tell me why.

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings?

Comment: `A(int n):b(n),a(b)` -- I know there must be a duplicate for this.  The question to you is -- which member gets initialized first, `a` or `b`?

Comment: The members are initialized in order of declaraion. So a first then b. So you can initialize b with a but not the other way around.

Comment: Every compiler I use — including the laughable one I wrote myself — warn about this problem.  Enable warnings.  Fix warnings.  Enjoy Vogon poetry.